# How to add Event Listener on Multiple tag at once

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm new in Javascript.  I have this images that I want to replace on the main-img. The code below is working fine but I just want to know how to do this by using less code in Javascript.

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="side-img">
            <img id="side1" onclick="side1()" src="img1.jpeg">
            <img id="side2" onclick="side2()" src="img2.jpeg">
            <img id="side3" onclick="side3()" src="img3.jpeg">
            <img id="side4" onclick="side4()" src="img4.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div id="main-img">
            <img id="main" src="img0.jpeg">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sideimg = document.querySelectorAll('#side-img img');
        var main = document.querySelector('#main');
    
             function side1() {
                main.src = sideimg[0].src;
             }
             function side2() {
                main.src = sideimg[1].src;
             }
             function side3() {
                main.src = sideimg[2].src;
             }
             function side4() {
                main.src = sideimg[3].src;
             }
            
        
    </script>
```

Comment: search for how to create slide show with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it by modifying the image tags like this:

```
<img id="side1" onclick="side(0)" src="img1.jpeg">
<img id="side2" onclick="side(1)" src="img2.jpeg">
<img id="side3" onclick="side(2)" src="img3.jpeg">
<img id="side4" onclick="side(3)" src="img4.jpeg">
```

And remove all side() functions in your JS script and add this function:

```
var sideimg = document.querySelectorAll('#side-img img');
var main = document.querySelector('#main');

function side(index) {
    main.src = sideimg[index].src;
}
```

Comment: Thankx for help brother.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically attach an onclick handler for each image.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
  img.onclick = () => {
    console.log(img.src)
    document.querySelector('#main').src = img.src
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="side-img">
    <img id="side1" src="img1.jpeg">
    <img id="side2" src="img2.jpeg">
    <img id="side3" src="img3.jpeg">
    <img id="side4" src="img4.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div id="main-img">
    <img id="main" src="img0.jpeg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
// retrieving the common ancestor element of the <img> elements:
let sideImage = document.querySelector('#side-img'),

// defining a named function, using arrow syntax; 'e' is a reference
// to the event object, passed automatically from the
// EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
  imageChange = (e) => {

    // we retrieve the element with the 'id' of 'main', and update
    // its src property to be that of the clicked element;
    // e.target retrieves the element upon which the event was
    // originally triggered:
    document.getElementById('main').src = e.target.src;
  };

sideImage.addEventListener('click', imageChange);
```

```js
let sideImage = document.querySelector('#side-img'),
  imageChange = (e) => {
    document.getElementById('main').src = e.target.src;
  };

sideImage.addEventListener('click', imageChange);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="side-img">
    <img id="side1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png?text=image1">
    <img id="side2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png?text=image2">
    <img id="side3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png?text=image3">
    <img id="side4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png?text=image4">
  </div>
  <div id="main-img">
    <img id="main" src="img0.jpeg">
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fhn6gqry/1/).

With reference to the question left in the comments, by the OP:

> Can you please explain to me how the container `#side-img` was looping through each image and adding an event listener to them?

Sure, in this case we used event-delegation taking advantage of the way that events bubble through the DOM.

Rather than binding an event-listener to multiple `<img>` elements we took advantage of the way that events bubble through the DOM; this means that we listened for the `click` event as it reaches the `#side-img`, and look at the `Event` Object's `target` property to find the element upon which the event was initially triggered.

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: can you please explain to me how the container #side-img was looping through each image and adding an event listener to them. and I'm sorry if my question was stupid

Answer (score 0):

Delegation included version

JS

```
const viewer = document.querySelector('#main');
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (typeof event.target.hasAttribute('data-clickable') && event.target.src) {
        viewer.src = event.target.src;
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="side-img">
    <img id="side1" data-clickable src="img1.jpeg">
    <img id="side2" data-clickable src="img2.jpeg">
    <img id="side3" data-clickable src="img3.jpeg">
    <img id="side4" data-clickable src="img4.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div id="main-img">
    <img id="main" src="img0.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```